# Серелизация и Десериализация объекта Json при помощи Gson

Tags: java, json, парсер, gson

Хочу распарсить ответ от сервера, использую при этом Gson. Основная цель каким-то образом унифицировать серелизацию и десерилизацию объекта.

Соответственно, существует 4 варианта ответа:

*Вариант 1* : items - это просто набор значений с тремя и более key-value значениями. Это первый тип данных.

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 456239048,
        "key1": "value_1",
        "key2": "value_2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*Вариант 2*: другой набор значений уже может иметь вложенный объект.

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 923,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "Test",
        "city": {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "city1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Test2",
        "last_name": "Test2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

И два последний варианта - ответы о состоянии.

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

И другой:

```
{
  "error": {
    "error_code": 14
  }
}
```

Соответственно я создал следующие классы:

```
public class DataModelDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonElement items=null;

        try{
            items = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Gson().fromJson(items, type);
    }
}
```

DataModel.java

```
public class DataModel {
private Response response;


public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    this.response = response;
}
```

}

Response.java

```
public class Response<T> {
private int count;
private List<T> items=new ArrayList<T>();
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public List<T> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<T> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

}

Items.java

```
public class Items {
    private int id;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

И проблема в том, что если я использую такую реализацию, то получаю ошибку.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.StringMap cannot be cast to com.app.Items
```

Проблема безусловно не в ней, а в том, что я не знаю, как организовать унифицированный парсинг ответа.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам в помощь инструмент для создания модельных классов http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Вводите в поле json, для которого нужно создать модельный класс

- source type: JSON
- annotation style: Gson

Лично я снимаю все остальные галочки, выставляю только "Use primitives types".

"Prewiew" - и ваш модельный класс готов! Ctrl+C Ctrl+V

ClassCastException появляется как раз тогда когда не может привести входящий от сервера JSON к вашей модельке

Так же стоит проверять код ответа от сервера, и приводить к модели только когда код ответа 200

Применительно к вопросу и к унификации: первые два ответа у Вас абсолютно идентичны, только в одном в массиве "items" один элемент, а во втором два: и к ним подходит следующий модельный класс:

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    public int count;
    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public class Item {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        public int id;
        @SerializedName("first_name")
        @Expose
        public String firstName;
        @SerializedName("last_name")
        @Expose
        public String lastName;
        @SerializedName("city")
        @Expose
        public City city;
    }

    public class Example {
        @SerializedName("response")
        @Expose
        public Response response;
    }

    public class City {
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        public int id;
        @SerializedName("title")
        @Expose
        public String title;
    }

}
```

Как я понимаю ответы о состоянии приходят при совсем других запросах, соответсвенно для них нужны свои модельные классы, зачем все лепить в одну кучу